# Parsing of custom format DateTime values in Web API routes

Tags: rest, datetime, url, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I'd like to use `DateTime` values in my routes like this:

```
/api/items/after/2015-08-01T08:00:00
```

but it's not working for the obvious reason:

> System.Web.HttpException: A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (:).

I don't want to escape `:`. Apparently, I need different format like `2015-08-01T08-00-00` for nice looking urls. It can be solved by changing default `DateTime` serialization format in Json.NET but in this case it will be applied globally. Or, I can try writing a custom binder. I wonder if there is a better (easier) approach. Maybe some configuration parameter the framework offers out of the box?

Answer (score 2):

The easies way to do this id the following:

- implement a class that has a DateTime property where you will deserialize the DateTime value, for example `DateTimeWrapper`
- define the route parameter as being of this class, instead of `DateTime`
- create a type converter which can convert the url segment string into your `DateTimeWrapper` class, by inheriting from `TypeConverter`. You can call it `DateTimeWrapperConverter`
- decorate your `DateTimeWrapper` class with an attribute like this `[TypeConverter(typeof(DateTimeWrapperConverter))]`

Once you've done this, when you receive the request, any route parameter of `DateTimeWrapper` class will be handled by your converter. Then you simply have to read the `DateTime` property of the `DateTimeWrapper` created by your custom converter.

In this way you avoid modifying the general behaviour for `DateTime` values.

This is a sample implementation, but the parsing itself is missing:

```
[TypeConverter(typeof(DateTimeWrapperConverter))]
public class DateTimeWrapper
{
    public DateTime Value { get; set; }
}

public class DateTimeWrapperConverter : TypeConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvertFrom(
       ITypeDescriptorContext context, Type sourceType)
    {
        if (sourceType == typeof (string))
        {
            return true;
        }
        return base.CanConvertFrom(context, sourceType);
    }

    public override object ConvertFrom(
         ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, object value)
    {
        if (value is string)
        {
            DateTimeWrapper wrapper = new DateTimeWrapper
            {
                Value = new DateTime() // parse the url segment !!
            };
            return wrapper;
        }
        return base.ConvertFrom(context, culture, value);
    }
}
```

You can test is wit a controller like this:

```
public class TestController : ApiController
{
    // GET api/<controller>/5
    public string Get(DateTimeWrapper id)
    {
        return id.Value.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    }
}
```

As the `id` is of type `DateTimeWrapper` it's converted with the custom converter.

If you want you can change the DateTimeWrapper so that it has an implicit convertion to `DateTime`, so that you don't need to read the `Value` property. Add this to the `DateTimeWrapper` class:

```
public static implicit operator DateTime(DateTimeWrapper wrapper)
{
    return wrapper.Value;
}
```

After this you can use an object of this class whenever a `DateTime` is expected.

*NOTE: changing the JSON.NET serializer would do nothing in this instance. It's only used to deserialize the payload of the HTTP request, but does nothing about the route parameters.*